# Can I integrate voice recognition feature in search widget in IOS as in google search bar?

Tags: ios, voice-recognition, siri

Can I integrate voice recognition feature in search widget in IOS as in google search bar?
Apple Siri can only be integrated separately and not with the search widget??
Also for apple siri I got openEars offline framework which itself is 72 MB large making my app size huge. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

The dictation feature is ready to use when you install iOS 8. You don’t need to add a new keyboard, and it works in any iOS application. However, you can only activate voice dictation using the default Apple iOS keyboard – it doesn’t show up in third-party keyboards.
The feature also requires an Internet connection to work. What you dictate is recorded and sent to Apple’s server, and in turn it converts what you say into text on your device. The feature will also access the names and nicknames in your device’s address book for more accurate spelling of names.